# how convert database data to json string

Tags: android, json, database

I have a table in database with 7 columns and want to send the column #0 and #6 of all rows to my server as json.

type of column 0 is Long and 6 is string.

my code:

```
Cursor c = datasource.db.rawQuery("select * from posts ",null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
                        do{
                            Object[] b = new Object[]{c.getLong(0),c.getString(6)};
                            list.add(b);
                        } while  (c.moveToNext());
                        JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);

                        Log.d("states",jsArray.toString());
                    }
```

my desired output is this:

> [[123,"hash1"],[125,"hash2"]]

but app gives me this output:

> ["[Ljava.lang.String;@b212d8b8","[Ljava.lang.String;@b212d998"]

Comment: Take a look at this here , might be helpful: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/05/c-convert-datatable-to-json-string-in-c.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need a array list of JSONArray with primitive type

```
ArrayList<JSONArray> list = new ArrayList<JSONArray>();
```

and add values this way

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(); 
jArray.put(c.getLong(0));
jArray.put(c.getLong(6));
list.add(jArray);
```